# Get the source code of a URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the source code of a page (let's say google.com) using Javascript. The code I tried is below but the issue remains the same which is that I am accessing a different domain. What I am trying to do is to check the source code of a page, check for a specific value in that source code and behave based on that information. Thanks!

> $.get(url, function(data){ something(data); }//end function(data)
>   );//end get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it if the page is from another domain and doesn't specifically allow it with [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). See the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

The only "workaround" is using a server, either fetching the source for you or acting as proxy.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing what I am trying to do? Basically get the source of a page to make sure it is the page that I am expecting, check something on that page to make sure of that and then once that check is valid, do whatever is the restin JS. What do you think? Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: The only good solution is to build on your server a service doing it for you.