# Get a Firefox/Chrome Web Extension to run a python script on a Nginx server

Tags: python, http, nginx, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a firefox/chrome web extension. Upon clicking the extension's button, I want to extract a string from the source code of a URL that is *not* the current active tab's URL. (Source code = the html file).

According to this post: [Get the source code of a URL using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302957/get-the-source-code-of-a-url-using-javascript) it is impossible to get the source code of an arbitrary URL absent setting up a server.

As such, I have used Amazon Web Services to set up an Nginx server. However, I'm a little confused on what to do from here. I've already written a script in python to fetch the source code of a URL and extract the target  string from it, so ideally, I would get my extension to run the script on the server and receive the output of the script.

How can I do this?

Also, the extension will provide a string to the python script, which will form the basis for the URL the python script will extract data from.

Comment: Simply perform `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`, parse with `DOMParser`, there are many examples. Your manifest.json should include the target URL in its `"permissions"`, see the documentation.

Comment: As a sidenote - the URL will change, (although the base domain of the URL will remain the same).

Comment: Also, are you saying that I should use a XMLHttpRequest with the Nginx server, or is the server not needed at all?

Comment: You'll see once you find the examples. Server is not needed. URL permissions can include all URLs via patterns.